# How to take a pointer of dialog class in a multithread function MFC

Tags: multithreading, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

i want to access my dialog box UI(edit box) in a multithread function which is i define global or independent function.
`CSampleDlg* m_dlg=(CSampleDlg*)_param;` here is _param is a parameter of thread function. when i tried this its crashing here : `ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));`

//here is sample code mfc

```
UINT MessageThread(LPVOID _param)
{
    CServerDlg* m_dlg=(CServerDlg*)_param; 
    char cChar[1024];
    CString strmsg=L"";

    while (!stopNow && (currValue < maxValue))
    {
        m_dlg->m_messagebox.GetWindowTextW(strmsg); //m_messagebox :editbox
        sprintf(cChar,"%s",CW2A(strmsg));
        char *buff=(char*)&cChar;
        m_dlg->m_server.Send(buff,sizeof(cChar));
        currValue++;
        Sleep(50);  
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever built your project in `Release` mode? or Are you in `Debug` mode? Please tell me what occurred after building your project as `Release`.

Answer (score 1):

Using CWnd pointers across threads is dangerous, if you want to access the window object behind it. CWnd pointers are stored in a per thread map. Using a window API function that is wrapped by the MFC may fail or throw an ASSERT.

You may use the embedded m_hWnd handle and you may use GetWindowText with this handle. But even isn't really a good solution.

UI and other workerthread actions should be strictly splitted. So better is to send the information you want to send to the workerthread y any other method than directly accessing the window.

Comment: thanks you can you give plz me a sample how to access window directly ?

Comment: I wrote it. You have the handle of the window. You can use the windows API. But other methods are better as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The `m_dlg->m_messagebox.GetWindowTextW(strmsg);` is very dangerous statement from a worker thread. Similarly its not advisable to pass pointer of `CDialog` accross threads.

Many solutions are possible for your problem even without passing pointer of `CDialog` to the thread.

I assume you want to track changes of text in an edit control in your dialog and pass it to a `server`using worker thread. You can choose to have a global buffer where you can copy text from edit control and then send notification to thread to send it. Don't forget to take `lock` over global buffer before copying data over it.

You can even think of using a `CList` object to maintain list of texts to be send to server. GUI will `push` texts to be send to server into `Clist` object.  And your thread can `pop` text (if available) from `CList` and send it to server.

Comment: thanks a lot for giving a direction i dont understand actually how to send data if i have not allow to access current class how to send data in thread through access current class member i should use it or not ?

Comment: You can pass instance of `m_server` to thread function which will enable you to send data. Best way is to have separate `ServerHandler` class which will have thread function and instance of socket. You UI needs to just make data available to `ServerHander` class to send to server.

Answer (score 0):

"How to take a pointer of dialog class in a multithread function MFC"?
You do not. Any object that has a handle including MFC window object should pass a handle to the thread. Handle is unique. if you send a pointer it will point to a different area (if any) in thread local storage.
Use Send/Post message API to send messages to the dialog.
You can use custom defined messages, or registered messages.